# App compatible issue in play store on my device

Tags: android, google-play, multiscreen

I have uploaded my android application in play store.[Link is here.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ibps.reasoning&hl=en) Minimum SDK version is 14. The problem is when i try to install in my **samsung galaxy tab(4.4.2)**, it is showing app is not compatible with this  device. What is the problem? please help me to solve this issue.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mygooglemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Can you tell me name of app? or link

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ibps.reasoning&hl=en

Comment: one more thing, is it a calling tab?I mean with sim card

Comment: Pls just see all your permissions carefully.Do you thing any permission included may not be available on this tab???

Comment: i have included in manifest also <supports-screens 
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

Comment: add more tags so that more people can see this

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll do that

Comment: Do you use any `<uses-feature>` in the Manifest? That might become an issue. Also check the developer console to verify if you have accidently added samsung galaxy tab to the list of incompamtable devices.

Comment: I see your app is not compatible with my Nexus 7 either. Post the permissions part of your manifest file, as well as any features declared.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire <uses-permission> and <uses-feature> part of your manifest there.

Comment: I see your reporting problems with tablet devices, maybe is it related to the telephony permission? either READ_PHONE_STATE or <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" ??